# Can't call a method from another class JAVA

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm making a number guessing program. A random number is generated, and the user tries to guess it. The program will print "too high" or "too low" and let the user guess again. I'm having an issue inputing guesses after the first one into the method that takes the guess.

Here is my class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab8
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        MyNumberGuess MyNumberGuess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());

        while (MyNumberGuess.tooLow() == true || MyNumberGuess.tooHigh() == true)
        {

            if (MyNumberGuess.tooHigh() == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Too high");
                System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                MyNumberGuess.MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
            }
            else if (MyNumberGuess.tooLow() == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Too low");
                System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                MyNumberGuess.MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Correct");
        System.out.println("You made " + MyNumberGuess.getNumGuesses() + " guesses");
    }
}
```

Here's the other class, and the problem method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyNumberGuess
{
    public static final int MAX_GUESS = 1000; 

    private int theNumber, numGuesses, prevGuess;

    public MyNumberGuess(int inGuess)
    {
       Random generator = new Random(); 
       numGuesses = 1;
       prevGuess = inGuess;
       theNumber = generator.nextInt(MAX_GUESS);
    }
}
```

As is, I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error when compiling in my first class on this line:

```
MyNumberGuess.MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

I've tried calling it in different ways, using parameters and not, and trying to call the variables alone, thought they are supposed to be private. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that a method or a constructor?

Comment: Try using `new MyNumberGuess(...)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: make that an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You previously used

```
MyNumberGuess MyNumberGuess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

to create an instance of your class. Why would you then use

```
MyNumberGuess.MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

to do the same thing?

This

```
public MyNumberGuess(int inGuess)
{
   Random generator = new Random(); 
   numGuesses = 1;
   prevGuess = inGuess;
   theNumber = generator.nextInt(MAX_GUESS);
}
```

is a constructor. You need to invoke it with the `new` operator.

Just re-initialize your variable

```
MyNumberGuess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

---

Note that java convention states that variables' names should begin with a lower case character.

---

On another note, this piece of code

```
  while (MyNumberGuess.tooLow() == true || MyNumberGuess.tooHigh() == true)
```

is redundant. The method call `MyNumberGuess.tooLow()` already returns a `true` or `false` value, so why compare it with `== true`? Just use it directly. For example

```
if (MyNumberGuess.tooLow()) // read it as "If my number guess is too low"
```

or

```
if (!MyNumberGuess.tooLow()) // read it as "If my number guess is not too low"
```

Apply that appropriately with the `while`.

Comment: Ahh, alright. So I did want to make the instance of my class. I renamed it just "guess". I tried calling it againt with (in.nextInt()) as the parameter, like this:          if (guess.tooHigh() == true)
            {
            System.out.println("Too high");
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            guess.MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());

but I still get a "cannot find symbol" error

Comment: @coin You still aren't creating a new instance. The notation `guess.MyNumberGuess(...` indicates that you are trying to call a method called `MyNumberGuess` on the object referenced by the variable `guess`. This is wrong. What you want is to reassign the `guess` variable to a new object. Use `guess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt())`.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with boolean methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the exact class name as the variable name

```
MyNumberGuess MyNumberGuess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

Change the casing if anything

```
MyNumberGuess myNumberGuess = new MyNumberGuess(in.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly bracket, you have your class definition and then you have a function definition but no ending semicolon. And you shouldn’t use the same name for so many variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird issue: no matter what I couldn't access the public methods of one of my classes whether it was static or whether I setup to instantiate it.  I ended up deleting the class and creating a new one with a different name.  I must have been stepping on a built in class name.